# How to close Child Process without affecting on the Parent Process

Tags: c#, forms, process, children

I have a Form **(MainForm)**. *MainForm* has a button to call **Editor.exe**. The exe caller code is displayed in the following:

```
private void InsertEquaButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = Process.Start(Editor.exe);
    string test = p.ProcessName;
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

**Editor.exe** is a separate executable file, which provides a user input form; after user input one image file in that form, and click OK button, it will close and that image will put into MainForm.

Here is the code of OK button:

```
.......
encoder.Save(s);// Save image to MainForm

var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Editor");
foreach (Process proc in processes)
{
    proc.CloseMainWindow(); // Propblem is here
    //   proc.Close();  
}
..........
```

*The problem is that when I click OK button in Editor, all apps (MainForm and Editor.exe) close.*

***So, how can I kill Editor.exe (Child Process) without killing MainForm process (Parent Process)?***

I have been try:

```
proc.close()
```

and

```
pro.Kill()
```

and

```
...
```

but they don't work.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you calling a totally separate executable rather than having the editor as a part of your project/solution?  Also, have you put a breakpoint in to check the contents of `processes`?

Comment: Why do you need to close processes manually? Can't you just do `this.Close()` in the OK button handler?

Comment: @Logarr : Because Editor.exe is another project that i can't put to my project . When i debug in processes content Editor process and MainForm process . But when i close Editor process then mainform process close immediately too

Comment: @KendallFrey : i have been try this.Close() but when form in Editor close then MainForm close too, i want close form in Editor but MainForm still alive to insert more input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem because my partner using thread to ourproject run faster, so when i close process in Editor it close thread . .... It is cause in question
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

May be the following link can help you to achieve what you want to do:

[Code Snippet: Terminate all child processes](http://www.shloemi.com/2013/03/code-snippet-terminate-all-child-processes/)

Comment: Thanks for your help in edit question and adv in chat forum ! My problem is that my partner using thread in Mainform that i do't know!